# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

after updating of hibernate and spring a get the following error for this query:

```
  @NamedQuery(name = "Payment.byAmount",
      query = "select p from Payment as p join p.application as a where p.amount = ?1 and p.channel = ?2 and p.type =?3 and p.created = ?4 and p.deletedDate is null and a.uuid = ?5")
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'a.id' [select count(p) from de.model.Payment p join p.application a1 where p.type = .....
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other query in that class? what is the version of Spring and Hibernate you are using?